# AppleScript: Create new file using custom New Text File dialog?

Tags: dialog, applescript

I just finished creating a script that would let me create a blank, untitled file in the currently focused finder window then focus on the file to quickly rename.

I'm looking to make use of the built-in New Text File dialog, but without File Format and Encoding.

[image: Yosemite New Text File Dialog]

Is there any way to create this dialog box?

Here is how I make a new file in the current location:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            set wasFolder to true
            set selectedFolder to first item of input
            set selectedType to (kind of (info for selectedFolder))

            if selectedType is not in {"Folder", "Volume"} then
                set selectedFolder to container of selectedFolder as string
                set wasFile to false
            end if
        end tell

        tell application "Finder"
            activate
            set theFile to make new file at folder selectedFolder
            if selectedFolder as string is equal to (path to desktop as string) then
                select window of desktop
                set selection to theFile as alias
            else
                reveal theFile
            end if
        end tell

        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Finder"
                if wasFolder then delay 0.4
                keystroke return
            end tell
        end tell
    on error errMsg
        display dialog "Error: " & errMsg
    end try
end run
```

Comment: Please use actual source code rather than an image in your question, and make note of the fact that your script is run as an Automator `Run AppleScript` action.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can now get [New File Menu](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/new-file-menu/id1064959555?mt=12) from the Mac App Store. It comes with a customizable preferences menu that lets you create new files with specific extensions.

Comment: Your question suggests that you want a _programmable_ solution. Please clarify how your answer relates to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of...

```
set userResonse to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a name..." default answer "response" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK")

tell application "Finder"
    if exists Finder window 1 then
        make new file at (target of front Finder window as text) with properties {name:userResonse}
    else
        make new file at (path to desktop) with properties {name:userResonse}
    end if
end tell
```